# MSSQL - Session has Open Transaction without a Transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

I'm researching an open transaction issue in relation to database updates from processing transactional MSMQ messages (see code-side [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863320/why-is-msmq-wcf-leaving-open-database-transactions)). These are enlisted in a distributed transaction and everything I've seen points to the transactions being completed and committed. However, when I check dm_exec_sessions, the connection has an open_transaction_count = 1. When I join out to dm_tran_database_transactions, I can't find a related transaction:

```
SELECT s.open_transaction_count, COUNT(t.transaction_id)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st on st.session_id = s.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_tran_database_transactions t ON t.transaction_id = st.transaction_id
GROUP BY s.open_transaction_count
```

`DBCC OPENTRAN` also shows no open transactions.

Anyone know what's going on as to why SQL is reporting an open transaction on the connection?

Comment: Is it possible the transaction is enlisted in a different database than the one you're looking?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for looking. No, I don't see a transaction belonging to the session on any other database.

Comment: Once you get started with queueing and distributed transactions I don't think you can always depend on the source session_id to be used for all interactions - sometimes those things will be handed off, so I would suggest widening your search.